# Elixir / Phoenix: How to implement session timeout / expiration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm working on a vanilla Elixir / Phoenix application and followed the general steps in the [Programming Phoenix](https://pragprog.com/book/phoenix/programming-phoenix) book to implement a basic sign in & sign out system (see snippets below). However I see no advice in the book or online about how to set up cookie-based Plug sessions to expire after a certain amount of time. What are some approaches to session timeout in Phoenix apps?

Here's some relevant snippets of my bare-bones auth system:

In `endpoint.ex`, the app is configured to use a read-only cookie-based session:

```
plug Plug.Session,
  store: :cookie,
  key: "_zb_key",
  signing_salt: "RANDOM HEX"
```

I wrote a plug `auth.ex` which (among other things) can log in an authenticated user, and can set `current_user` based on the session `user_id` found in subsequent requests:

```
def login!(conn, user) do
  conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
end

# ... more ...

def load_current_user(conn, _opts) do
  cond do
    conn.assigns[:current_user] ->
      conn # If :current_user was already set, honor it
    user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id) ->
      user = Zb.Repo.get!(Zb.User, user_id)
      assign(conn, :current_user, user)
    true ->
      conn # No user_id was found; make no changes
  end
end

# ... more ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I first looked for cookie expiration options in [the Plug library](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Session.html), then realized that an easier (and more secure) approach is to simply set an expiration datetime in the session along with the user_id. The session is tamper-proof, so when I receive each request, I can compare the datetime to now; if the session hasn't yet expired, I set `current_user` as normal. Otherwise I call `logout!` to delete the expired session.

An implementation would look something like this (requires the [Timex](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex) library):

```
# Assign current_user to the conn, if a user is logged in
def load_current_user(conn, _opts) do
  cond do
    no_login_session?(conn) ->
      conn # No user_id was found; make no changes
    current_user_already_set?(conn) ->
      conn
    session_expired?(conn) ->
      logout!(conn)
    user = load_user_from_session(conn) ->
      conn
        |> put_session(:expires_at, new_expiration_datetime_string)
        |> assign(:current_user, user)
  end
end

defp session_expired?(conn) do
  expires_at = get_session(conn, :expires_at) |> Timex.parse!("{ISO:Extended}")
  Timex.after?(Timex.now, expires_at)
end

# ... more ...

# Start a logged-in session for an (already authenticated) user
def login!(conn, user) do
  conn
    |> assign(:current_user, user)
    |> put_session(:user_id, user.id)
    |> put_session(:expires_at, new_expiration_datetime_string)
    |> configure_session(renew: true)
end

defp new_expiration_datetime_string do
  Timex.now |> Timex.shift(hours: +2) |> Timex.format("{ISO:Extended}")
end

# ... more ...
```

Answer (score 11):

The Plug.Sessions module has a built-in option to set the expiration of a cookie using the `max_age` key. For example, extending your `endpoint.ex` snippet would look like:

```
plug Plug.Session,
  store: :cookie,
  key: "_zb_key",
  signing_salt: "RANDOM HEX",
  max_age: 24*60*60*37       # 37 days
```

Credit: https://teamgaslight.com/blog/til-how-to-explicitly-set-session-expiration-in-phoenix

Documentation: https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Session.html#module-options

Answer (score 8):

This is our production solution
([view in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/qertoip/87b6df3d8c15bb51ea868d53fcbe6736)):

`sliding_session_timeout.ex`

```rb
defmodule Auth.SlidingSessionTimeout do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts \\ []) do
    Keyword.merge([timeout_after_seconds: 3600], opts)
  end

  def call(conn, opts) do
    timeout_at = get_session(conn, :session_timeout_at)
    if timeout_at && now() > timeout_at do
      logout_user(conn)
    else
      put_session(conn, :session_timeout_at, new_session_timeout_at(opts[:timeout_after_seconds]))
    end
  end

  defp logout_user(conn) do
    conn
    |> clear_session()
    |> configure_session([:renew])
    |> assign(:session_timeout, true)
  end

  defp now do
    DateTime.utc_now() |> DateTime.to_unix
  end

  defp new_session_timeout_at(timeout_after_seconds) do
    now() + timeout_after_seconds
  end
end
```

#### How to use it

Plug it at the end of your `:browser` pipeline in your Phoenix app’s `router.ex`.

Please note that authentication (getting `user_id` from the session, loading the user from the DB) and authorization are concerns for other plugs, further in the pipeline. So make sure it is plugged before your session-based authentication and authorization Plugs.

```rb
pipeline :browser do
  plug :accepts, ["html"]
  plug :fetch_session
  plug :fetch_flash
  plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  plug Auth.SlidingSessionTimeout, timeout_after_seconds: 3600    # <=
end
```